# Regarding Scopes of EJB Beans

Tags: jsf, ejb

I have read somewhere that the default scope of all EJB beans(Stateless,Stateful and Singleton) is dependent scope. Dependent scope means there scope depends on the beans in which they are injected. SO, I try to test this concept.

I have a Request scope managed bean called A. I am injecting a Stateless bean B into A whose scope is by default dependent. So, B scope is dependent on A which is request scoped. So for every new request, there should be different instances of A and B. But I'm not getting it. When I run code for two different requests, I'm getting different instances of A but same instances of B. Why?

Secondly, When I'm injecting a dependent scope Stateful Bean C into A, i'm getting two different instances of A and C for two different requests. That must also occur in the case of stateless bean but it is not happening.

If I injecting a Singleton bean D with default dependent scope into bean A, for two different requests, Similar to first case, I'm getting different instances of A bean bit same instances of C bean why?

According to my understanding, when a bean is in default scope dependent, whether it is stateless,stateful or singleton, it scope depends upon the bean in which it is injecting. So if the Bean A is request  scoped, all the bean injecting into A with dependent scope must become request scoped and must have different instances for different requests. Can somebody explain this to me why is it not happening?

Comment: Don't forget that ejb's are pooled. So to my understanding, if you test it to be the same instance by using it's hash/toString(), you might get the same one from the pool again and again…

Comment: But it is getting different instances for stateful bean and same instances for stateless/singleton bean. Also, I am not only checking the same instances using hash/toString() method but also checking the instance variables initialized by those objects. For the two different requests, singleton/stateless bean have same instances and both instances have same value for the instance vriables.